# Access denied error when running the website from external drive

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, permission-denied, access-denied

I have an ASP.NET MVC website running locally. I have a copy of the website on my external hard disk and I have updated website's physical path to the external hard disk location.

But I am getting the error

> Access to the path 'D:\Sites\Sitecore 10.1\website\bin\roslyn\csc.exe' is denied.

I have given the group `Everyone` security access to the website folder `D:\Sites\Sitecore 10.1\website` but the access denied error is still there.

Anything I can do to run the website from external hard disk?

Comment: You have to change permission for IIS user in new path.

Comment: Its already there and i have also added the Everyone user with all the permissions

Comment: Take a look to follow link:  https://www.diskpart.com/tips-tricks/external-hard-drive-access-denied-0310.html